# Every combination of www and https:// working but not plain https://? (Heroku and Namecheap)

Tags: heroku, https, dns, web-hosting, namecheap

So here's a list of what works:

- http://schoold.io
- https://www.schoold.io
- schoold.io

And this doesn't work

- https://schoold.io

I only use heroku and namecheap so I'm not messing with any server configs, it's all configured using the heroku and namecheap UI. Anyone know how to get https://schoold.com to work? I'm getting a connection timeout. Here's a pic of the configs:[image]

[image]

Comment: You have ssl certificate issued for www.schoold.io. It does not work with schoold.io.
Not sure why server hangs instead of complaining about non valid certificate. Separate certificate for schoold.io or wildcard certificate for *.schoold.io should solve the problem.

Comment: Just tried with Safari and Firefox and it works when I enter schoold.io. Idk, weird behavior with Chrome I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I think Chrome had an issue with some cached redirects. I cleared browser history and it seems to work now.